# Read two strings from file separated by space in C

Tags: c, gcc, readfile

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char* username, *password;
    cout<<"Content-type: text/html"<<endl<<endl;
    FILE *in = fopen("useri.txt","r");
    while (fscanf(in,"%s %s",username, password) != EOF) {
        cout<<username<<endl;
    }
    fclose(in);
}
```

The file looks like:

```
admin admin
```

For some reason, all the text in the specific file, is being read into the `username` var. The code as-is, does print out both the 2 values I have in my file (on separate lines), but that's wrong, cause it should only print 1.

As soon as I try to print `password`, the program just exits, with no error (not even segmentation fault). Am I doing something wrong?

**Note**: I need this to stay C, not C++ (except for the `cout` part, because I'm lazy).

Comment: Wait? You say it's C yet you use `endl` and `cout` which is C++. So what are you using?

Comment: `scanf` does not allocate space for the strings. You must do it yourself.

Comment: I didn't know that. I allocated the space and it works, thanks!

Comment: @TonyTheLion: uhm, did you read the last part of my post? *except for the cout part, because I'm lazy*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory is not allocated to variables.

```
char* username, *password;
```

use `malloc()` to allocate memory dynamically.

It is not mandatory to use only dynamic memory. you can use static memory also. i.e

```
//100 is just a sample value. 
//Modify as per your requirement.
#define MAX_STR_LEN 100    

char  username[MAX_STR_LEN], password[MAX_STR_LEN];
```

Comment: You are a genius! Thanks! Works now :)

Comment: Either allocate on heap with `malloc`/`calloc` _or_ allocate on stack as arrays.

Comment: There is no reason to use dynamic memory for this, it is probably a bad idea even, since the max length of username and password is most likely known at compile time.

Comment: correct @Lundin. Simply pointed out his mistake. Im not suggesting to use only dynamic memory allocation. Updated.